# Removing text from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which works:

```
classes = $(this).attr("class").split('_');
```

If `$(this)`'s class was:

```
class="billed_department_employee_client_code"
```

The end result would look like this:

```
["billed", "department", "employee", "client", "code"]
```

This is exactly what I want as it allows me to do stuff like this

```
console.log( classes[0] );
console.log( classes[1] );
console.log( classes[2] );
console.log( classes[3] );
```

Is it possible to remove a single value from `classes` and move the rest of the values back?

For example,

if `classes` contains `department`, remove it.  So, if it looks like this:

```
["billed", "department", "employee", "client", "code"]
```

it should become:

```
["billed", "employee", "client", "code"]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried? Did you make an attempt to find the answer?

Comment: If you know the index then use splice, if you want to search the word, use jQuery's grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `splice()` method.

```
classes.splice(1, 1);
```

will remove 1 item (second parameter) starting from index 1 (first parameter). If you don't know the index, you can use `indexOf()` to find it.

Some browsers do not support `indexOf()` so you can use the script from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to use it. You'll also need to check to make sure `indexOf()` doesn't return `-1` (not found) as passing in negative parameter for index into `splice()` will cause it to remove items from the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It can be done. This way:

```
var c = ["billed", "department", "employee", "client", "code"];
c.splice( c.indexOf('department'), 1); // will remove 'department' from the array.
c.join("_"); // will return "billed_employee_client_code"
```

Comment: Now what was the downvote for?

Comment: Maybe if you test your answer, you'll figure it out.

Comment: updated. was using `slice` instead of `splice`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if you're using a relative modern browser (you can always apply a shim for the rest). So:

```
var pos = classes.indexOf("department");

if (pos > -1) {
    classes.splice(pos, 1);
}

$(this).attr("class", classes.join("_"));
```

Comment: Will splice and indexOf work on IE8?

Comment: @oshirowanen `splice` will work but unfortunately IE8 is not considered a "modern browser", so you have to apply a shim for `indexOf` as described in the related link. If you're using jQuery you could use [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead, or if you're using underscore you have an [indexOf](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf) implementation.